# What happens if I pthread_create while holding a lock?

Tags: pthreads, mutex

Suppose I have the following situation. I have a thread, and this thread is holding a lock. While it's doing so, I call pthread_create, so now I have two threads. Suppose the second thread gets to unlock the lock. What happens when the first thread hits the unlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thread should only unlock a lock that it has locked itself, and thus your second thread should not attempt to unlock a mutex that has been locked by the first thread.

Trying to unlock a mutex that has been locked by another thread is undefined behavior, unless the mutex type is `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK`, in which case an error is returned.

More info here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock

Relevant section:

> If the mutex type is PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL, deadlock detection shall
>   not be provided. Attempting to relock the mutex causes deadlock. If a
>   thread attempts to unlock a mutex that it has not locked or a mutex
>   which is unlocked, undefined behavior results.
>
> If the mutex type is PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK, then error checking
>   shall be provided. If a thread attempts to relock a mutex that it has
>   already locked, an error shall be returned. If a thread attempts to
>   unlock a mutex that it has not locked or a mutex which is unlocked, an
>   error shall be returned.